# Is primary key auto increment always needed in a table?

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key

I have a table which represents users connected to a game room. It looks like this:

```
id | gameRoomId | userId
------------------------
 0    abc          bob
 1    xyz          joe
 2    xyz          frank
 ...
```

Is there a way I can remove the auto-increment primary-key `id` column? I'm not using it for any queries, and don't plan to.

The `gameRoomId` and `userId` have a generic index on them individually.

I'm using mysql now, might switch to postgres eventually, if it matters.

Comment: so when the user disconnect how you remove it from the game room table?

Comment: There's natural keys which is what the composite of GameRoomID and userID represents.  and there are Surrogate keys which have no meaning other than being unique.  In general system design; it often makes sens to have a surrogate key.  1) it allows you to get a dataset based on ONE value instead of a combined key values 2) it doesn't change when the Key itself changes and thus relationships are easier to maintain.  But both schools of thought work. http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html

Comment: Recently i started adding identity columns to these types of tables, but only because Entity Framework would complain if they did not have one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not obligatory for a table to have a primary key constraint.  Where a table does have a primary key, it is not obligatory for that key to be automatically generated.  In some cases, there is no meaningful sense in which a given primary key even *could* be automatically generated.

You should be able to remove your existing primary key column from the database like so:

```
alter table my_table drop column id;
```

or perhaps you can avoid creating it in the first place.

Whether this is a wise thing to do depends on your circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

Your table looks like a relationship table.  It represents the many-to-many relationship between gamerooms and users.  Assuming that a given combination of the two can occur only once (which seems reasonable), you could declare a composite primary key of those two columns, and do without the id field.

Some design tools require a simple primary key, but that's not part of relational modeling as such.

At the physical level, declaring a primary key would have a variety of consequences.  The index created for you would be a compound one. It would be slightly more efificient if you used integers for userids and gemeroomids, instead of the character strings you have shown.

As far as not declaring any primary key goes, I don't recommend that.  Sooner or later, you'll have a bug in your application that lets duplicate rows in there, and you'll start to get unexpected results from your queries.  It's far better to let the DBMS help you manage your data.

Answer (score 2):

No.

A primary key must be unique and that has to be 100% guaranteed, and NON NULL
A primary key should be stable if ever possible and not change.
So you don't have to, but it's a good choice since there is no other naturally unique data and you don't want to have enormous primary keys.

To answer your sub-question, you wouldn't really want to, it's not taking that much data and it's unique.